# resizable is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have included the jquery ui in my page and try to appliy resizable to img but it is not working.

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$('.jqte_editor').on('mouseup', 'img', function() {
  $('.jqte_editor img').draggable().resizable();
});
```

but it says resizable is not recognized.

**Edit**
actually in this case it says Draggable is not recognized whatever is coming from jqueryui

Comment: Have you also included jQuery core?

Comment: what do you mean by core.. I have included the normal jquery version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

That means either `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js` path is not correct or required modules `draggable`, `resizable` are not included

Add this and try

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If doesn't work then you may have included other JS library with jQuery like Prototype or Mootools

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xVZp/)

Comment: when I was downloading the ui the draggable checkbox was checked.

Comment: Add this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and try

Comment: No there are no mootools or prototype. I think

Comment: Working demo added in answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope you added the jQuery lib too, because it not showing any error about `.on()`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also instead of `mouseup` you can directly have

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.jqte_editor img').draggable().resizable(); 
});
```

Check the working [**sample fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Mpt/1/).

Comment: i am dragging img on the editor surface in that case I need delegated event I think